# Non-constant expressions cannot be multiplied - PuLP Package

Tags: python, optimization, pulp

I am working on an optimisation problem for which I am using PuLP linear programming package.
Please find my linear programming model parameters below:

```py
#model
model = LpProblem(name="variable_rate", sense = LpMaximize)

# Defining variable
var_rate = LpVariable.dicts("variable_rate", len, lowBound=10, upBound=26, cat='integer') 

expression = variable_x*var_rate*var_rate #part of the expression
```

I get the error `TypeError: Non-constant expressions cannot be multiplied`

So, if my expression involves multiplication of the `LpVariable`, I get this error. I read that PuLP is a linear programming package and accepts only addition or subtraction within the `LpVariable`.
But I need to have that multiplication factor in my expression. Is there a way I can solve this problem with PuLP or do you suggest any other optimisation package.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: PuLP is for **linear** problems. The product of two variables is not linear (obviously) and thus, isn't supported as your error message indicates. Either use a library for mixed-integer nonlinear programming or try to linearize your constraints, see [here](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/7293/how-to-linearize-the-product-of-two-integer-variables) for more details.